# Is there a good library for WMS "Tile Servers"?

Tags: open-source-gis, openlayers-2, embeddable-web-maps

I am looking for WMS Tile Servers that I can consume with "[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org)".

**One:** Are there any good library / resources online that collate WMS tile servers or where is a good place to start looking? (Street maps & others etc)

**Two:** Are there any **free** tile servers available?

Comment: Are you looking for software to host your own map tiles, or services that publish map tiles you can display?

Comment: Services that publish map tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to your first question:

For base maps, such as Google Maps or the Open Street Map, a good place to start is the [OpenLayers Example Showcase](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/).  The following is just a subset of the examples that fetch data from Tile Servers:

- [All Overlays with Google and OSM](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/all-overlays-google.html)
- [Base Layers Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/baseLayers.html)
- [Bing Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/bing.html)

For each example, right click and use "View Page Source" to see the javascript that loads layers from the servers.

For your second question:

The free map servers I have worked with are:

- [MapServer](http://www.mapserver.org/)
- [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/)

In my experience, GeoServer was the easiest to set up quickly due to the fact that it is written in Java.

Comment: MapServer and Geoserver are both full WMS servers and not tile servers. MapProxy, TileCache (both for Unix/Windows) and GeoWebCache (Java) are tile servers that support TMS and WMS-C.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a directory of available (e.g. public) servers that specializes in tiled WMS, but I do know that GeoWebCache is a freely available implementation of a WMS tile server:

http://geowebcache.org/trac

GeoWebCache is released under the Lesser GPL.  It works well with Openlayers!

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) which is also written in Python but it released under AGPL 3.0 licence.

It can actually do simple reprojections and layer combining, using PIL(python imaging library) in the background with very good results.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the Java powered GeoWebCache, you can also use TileCache, written in Python:

http://tilecache.org/

It is released under the BSD license and works like a charm with OpenLayers too

Answer (score 3):

In the services departement, there is also MapBox tile servers: http://mapbox.com/tiles

Comment: This link is dead. Are there any free WMS servers (not server software but open public endpoints to fetch tiles from) ?

Comment: @codecowboy: Probably meant: http://tiles.mapbox.com/